# Clone private github repo to launched EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, paramiko

I'm building a scrip that launches and connects to an EC2 instance. After all setup of the instance I have to copy my private repo to it, and then run it. The code works fine for public repo.
Also if I manually launch an instance, connect to it and run line by line, it also works fine. I'm using python, boto3 and paramiko.

Here is what I have so far:

```py
print("Creating ssh key pair...")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@gmail.com" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N ""')
    output = stdout.read().decode()
    print(output)
    print("Done")

    # add ssh key to ssh-agent
    print("Adding ssh key to ssh agent")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" ; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa')
    output = stdout.read().decode()
    print(output)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts')
    output = stdout.read().decode()
    print(output)

    # add ssh key to github account
    print("Adding ssh key to github account...")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('curl -u "myusername:mytoken" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"title\":\"EC2_Instance_Key\",\"key\":\"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)\"}" https://api.github.com/user/keys -X POST')
    output = stdout.read().decode()
    print(output)
    print("Done")

    # clone the repository
    print("Cloning the repository to the instance...")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('git clone -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" git@github.com:myOrganization/ec2_test.git /home/ec2-user/project')
    output = stdout.read().decode()
    print(output)
    print("Done")
```

I am getting this error:

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
> Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDH50Rl curl: (3) unmatched close
> brace/bracket in URL position 18: myemail@gmail.com}

Comment: After some debuging I think the problem is where I add the ssh key to my github account. But I still can't figure it out why it works fine manually doing on a ssh connection but not when I run the scrip.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the problem is. Does the script fail for private repos? And is there any error message?

Comment: If I run the commands manually in a ssh connection to an EC2 instance it works fine. But with the scrip it is not adding the public key to my github account. It doesn't output any erros.

Comment: **Side-note:** Rather than using SSH to configure an instance, you should consider passing a script via User Data. It will automatically execute on the first boot. See: [Run commands on your Linux instance at launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this taking a different approach a using github CLI.

Setting the GH TOKEN variable to my token gave the instance the privileges to add the public key to my github account.

```
print("Creating ssh key pair...")
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@email.com" -f /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa -N ""')
print(stdout.read().decode())
print(stderr.read().decode())
print("Done")

print("Adding ssh key to ssh agent...")
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" ; ssh-add /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa')
print(stdout.read().decode())
print(stderr.read().decode())
print("Done")

print("Adding github to known hosts...")
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ssh-keyscan github.com >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts')
print(stdout.read().decode())
print(stderr.read().decode())
print("Done")

print("Installing github cli...")
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sudo yum -y install wget ; wget https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/download/v2.15.0/gh_2.15.0_linux_amd64.rpm ; sudo rpm -i gh_2.15.0_linux_amd64.rpm ; gh --version')
print(stdout.read().decode())
print(stderr.read().decode())
print("Done")


print("Setting GH TOKEN...")
title = project_id + '_' + instance_id
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('export GH_TOKEN=mytoken; echo $GH_TOKEN ; gh ssh-key add /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub --title '+title)
print(stdout.read().decode())
print(stderr.read().decode())
print("Done")

print("Cloning the repository to the instance...")
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('git clone -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" git@github.com:myOrganization/'+repository+'.git /home/ec2-user/project')
print(stdout.read().decode())
print(stderr.read().decode())
print("Done")
```